# Fibonacci in Java using Dynamic Programming and Recursions

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, dynamic-programming, filewriter

I'm new to Dynamic Programming so I tried to create a file and write it onto Array.txt in the download section. The logic is:

```
If the Array is longer than the current array: Extend the array and copy to old array onto the new one
```

I, however, can't find a way to actually copy the section of the old array onto the new one.
The way that I am using right now is

```java
System.arraycopy()
```

Here is the code:
(Remember to swap out YOURUSERNAME with your current username on the computer to avoid getting an error)

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Fibonacci {

    static void createFile() {
        try {
            File Array = new File("C:\\Users\\YOURUSERNAME\\Downloads\\Array.txt");
            if (Array.createNewFile()) {
                System.out.println("File created: " + Array.getName());
            } else {
                System.out.println("File already exists.");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void fileWrite(int[] array, int num) {
        try {
            FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\YOURUSERNAME\\Downloads\\Array.txt");
            if (num <= array.length) {
                int[] newA = new int[array.length];
                System.arraycopy(array, 0, newA, 0, array.length);
                myWriter.write(Arrays.toString(newA));
                myWriter.close();
            }
            System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    static int[] fileRead(int[] Array1) {
        try {
            StringBuilder dataTotal = new StringBuilder();
            File Array = new File("C:\\Users\\YOURUSERNAME\\Downloads\\Array.txt");
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(Array);
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = myReader.nextLine();
                dataTotal.append(data);
            }
            myReader.close();
            System.out.println(dataTotal);
            dataTotal.deleteCharAt(0);
            dataTotal.deleteCharAt(dataTotal.length() - 1);
            String[] array1 = dataTotal.toString().split(", ");
            int[] array = new int[array1.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
                array[i] = Integer.parseInt(array1[i]);
            }
            return array;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    static int[] arrayCreator(int num) {
        return new int[num];
    }

    static int fib(int num, int[] array1) {
        int[] array = fileRead(array1);
        if (num == 1 || num == 2) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            assert array != null;
            if(array[num - 1] > 0) {
                return array[num - 1];
            } else {
                array[num - 1] = fib(num - 1, array1) + fib (num - 2, array1);
                fileWrite(array, num);
            }
        }
        return array[num - 1];
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 10;


        int[] array = arrayCreator(num);
        createFile();
        fileWrite(array, num);
        System.out.println(fib(num, array));
    }
}
```

Comment: The `fileWrite()` method should only be responsible for writing an array to file, it should not be doing any array copying. Your code should be building the array in memory, and only calling `fileWrite()` **once** at the end. Take a step back and re-think what you're doing.

Comment: I think using fileWrite() to copy the array then write it in the text file is the most logical thing to do because it saves a lot of time to complile as I don't need to add a new function just to use it once.

Comment: Writing to a file takes time, so by writing entire content to the file repeated, rather than waiting until the end, will certainly *not* "save a lot of time", it will unnecessarily slow down the program (a lot). --- Also, the programming guideline of "separation of concern" means that a method called `writeFile` should do just that, white the content of **an** array to file. It shouldn't be responsible for copying values from one array to another.

Comment: Ok, so I should make another function?

Comment: I don't know. Why would you make another function. Where is it that you need the array to be bigger than it currently is? Why wouldn't you extend the array length at that point in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend an array by one element, you have two choices:

- Using [`System.arraycopy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-)

  ```
  int[] newArray = new int[array.length + 1];
  System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArray, 0, array.length);
  array = newArray;
  ```
- Using [`Arrays.copyOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-)

  ```
  array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + 1);
  ```

Comment: I didn't want to extend the array by one element, I wanted it to copy over the results that exist to the new array that's not limited to 1 more element only

Comment: @MaxPan That is an ***example***. Specify whatever new size you want the new array to have.

Comment: Ok, but isn't that what I have done in the code?

System.arraycopy(arrayO, 0, array, 0, arrayO.length);

Comment: @MaxPan Where are you doing that? The only `arraycopy()` that I can see is in the `fileWrite()` method, where it certainly doesn't belong, and you always call it with same array as both parameters, so where are you doing the *"extend the array and copy old array onto the new one"* as instructed?

Comment: Ok, instead of that, I made it so the parameter is "int num, int[] array" where num is the number of elements and array is the array to be updated. You can see the new fileWrite() in the post again.

Comment: @MaxPan What is the point of that? Any values beyond what was in the original array will all the 0. Don't you want to write actual values, instead of 0's? And the re-sized array is then discarded, so the caller of the method still only has the shorter array, so what was the point of extending the array? It makes absolutely no sense for the `writeFile` method to be doing the array extension logic. And then you only do anything at all in there when `num <= array.length`, i.e. you're never extending the array at all, and **extend** is the entire point. You're not extending anything!